# Writing my APIs in Scala using Play framework. What's the easiest way to implement OAuth?

Tags: scala, oauth, playframework

I'm writing REST APIs in Scala. It has been a good experience but now I want to implement the user registration part. The industry standard being OAuth 2.0, I would like to implement an easier version of OAuth(1 or 2). Now, I've no clue what is the easiest way to implement it? Do I've to write the entire thing myself or are there any libraries that might make my life easier?

Comment: its actually pretty easy - just refer to google/ twitter api pages and they have a full walk through. btw why dont you use the SecureSocial module?

Comment: Because 1. It is supporting twitter OAuth1 and not OAuth2. Also, no support for Username/Password.

Comment: Puck: https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/ says it supports both. Are you sure? Are they sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried integrating socialauth in my application, and it was really simple. You can follow the   guide at http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStarted#Step_3._Implementation.

It takes care of all the specifics for you and supports all the "usual providers".

I had to make two adaptions for play 2.0 and scala:

1. store the SocialAuthManager in the play cache since we have no server sessions
2. SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap needs a servlet request to construct the paramsMap. I used the following code in my callback action instead:

   req.queryString.map { p =>
         p._1 -> p._2.head
       }.asJava

   (.asJava needs "import scala.collection.JavaConversions._")